# grails 2.4 - jquery not being included

Tags: grails

I'm trying to do the example from the Manning "Grails in Action": the gsp's

```
<g:javascript library="jquery" />
```

is becoming

```
<script src="/qotd/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript" library="jquery"></script>
```

but that URL doesn't work.   BuildConfig.groovy has

```
    plugins {
//...
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
```

I might have missed a step in typing things in, or it might be a 2.3->2.4 Asset issue?

Comment: By default 2.4 loads in jquery - no need to initialise it. 2.4 Has moved to assets and the configuration for javascript is done via grails-app/assets/java scripts - there is an application.js in there that loads in jquery. Try creating a default app then load up the page in your browser and do view source - you should find jquery loaded in

Comment: If you're using the `assets-pipeline` or `resources` plugin you shouldn't be using the `<g:javascript>` tag at all. What you should do depends on which of those two plugins you *are* using

Comment: This is the default app, the one made with "grails create-app"
@Dónal, How do I specify one of those two plugins?

Comment: I see jquery there, roughly, but not sure of the 2.4 way of referencing it?
Like I see it in the target:
 ~/dev/grails/qotd$ > find . -name "*js" | grep -i jq
./target/work/plugins/jquery-1.11.1/grails-app/assets/javascripts/jquery.js
./target/work/plugins/jquery-1.11.1/web-app/js
./target/work/plugins/jquery-1.11.1/web-app/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.js
./target/work/plugins/jquery-1.11.1/web-app/js/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js